# How to calculate the angle between 2 vectors in a plane.

Tags: vectors, angle

Suppose we have 2 directional (not starting from the origin(0,0)) vectors u and v that are `2D` vectors. Suppose (u and v) vectors can have any direction and can lie in any quadrant. The question is there a formula to find the angle between them?
Here is an image for more illustration:

[image]

After long search i found that i can use `ATAN2()` function for that, but the `ATAN2()` takes 2 positional vectors am i right?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878785/how-to-find-an-angle-in-range0-360-between-2-vectors/879474#879474

Comment: You can translate the vectors without  changing the angle between them. So translate both tails to the origin. That make it any easier?

Comment: Which vectors have you given?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner i have the vector P1P2 and want to get the angle between P1P2 extension and (P1P3 or P1P4 or P1P5) so i am looking for a general formula for that

Comment: @AugSB very helpful thank you

Comment: @JohnForkosh smart idea, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $u = (x, y)$ and $v = (a, b)$.

Let 
$$
w = (-y, x)
$$
and compute 
\begin{align}
c &= v \cdot u \\
s &= v \cdot w 
\end{align}
Then the angle from $u$ to $v$ is exactly $atan2(s, c)$.

Details: 
The "dot product" of two vectors $(p, q)$ and $(r, s)$ is $pr + qs$. The length $\| x \|$ of a vector $(p, q)$ is $\sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$. So the formulas for $c$ and $s$ become
\begin{align}
c &= ax + by\\
s &= -ay + bx.
\end{align}

The only problem that can arise is that $c = s = 0$, in which case the value returned by atan2 will not be meaningful. This only happens when either $u$ or $v$ is the zero vector (or both are!), in which case the angle between them is undefined anyhow.

One last thing: you've asked for the angle measured CLOCKWISE, but my answer gives the angle measured COUNTERclockwise, because that's a really well-established standard in mathematics. If you want a clockwise angle, you'll need to negate the result that my formula gives you.

Comment: True -- good point. I shouldn't try to write answers before that first cup of tea. I'll edit.

Comment: Then the angle from u to v is exactly ATAN2(s,c) is similar to the ATAN2(determinant,dotProduct)

Comment: If you want to call "s" and "c" by the names "determinant" and "dotProduct", I suppose so...but I chose "s" and "c" because those items are proportional to the sine and cosine of the angle you want.

Comment: +1 beautifully concise and clear answer